# Problem with use of map function in react for setting text and color of buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I will like to have buttons from array with colored text. 
I use ReactJS and I have this code in my *app.js* :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const myArray=["orange","red","yellow","green","blue","yellow"];

class App extends Component {
     render() {
          // this work
          const buttons=myArray.map((color,i)=><button key={i} style={color={color}}> my test </button> )

          //**// but this don't work**
         // const buttons=myArray.map((color,i)=><button key={i} style={color={color}}> {color} </button> )

          // and this work                          
          const buttons2=myArray.map((color,i)=><button  key={i}>{color}</button>)

           return (
                 <div>
                     <div>{buttons}</div>
                     <div>{buttons2}</div>  
                 </div>
               );
     }
}
export default App;
```

[image: Screenshot of app]

When I use `{color}` twice it gives me an error. Why is that? Can someone explain to me?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: '@Murat Karagöz' had the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your both versions should not work. You need to define a `style` object. Which should look like this

```
style={{color: color}}
```

with that

```
const buttons = myArray.map((color, i) => <button key={i} style={{ color: color }}> {color} </button>)
```

Comment: My first work because i wrote style={color={color}} instead of style={color={color:color}} that is ok with ES6

Answer (score 0):

I think this question finded a good answer by @ MuratKaragöz